# How to add scroll bar in popup window by JavaScript/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## This javaScript code where i want to add scroll bar.

- function alertMessage
- @param cls string defines css class
- @param heading string message header
- @param message string message body
- examples:
- cls 'blue' for normal alert
- cls 'red' for error alert
- cls 'green' for success alert
- cls 'yellow' for warning alert

`function alertMessage(x, cls, heading, message) {`

   `$.confirm({
        'title': heading,
        'message': message,
        'class': cls,
        'buttons': {
            'OK': {
                'class': cls,
                'action': function () {
                }
            }
        }
    });
}`

Answer (score 0):

In class cls make overflow auto or overflow-y or overflow-x:scroll  according to your requirement